# Permanently change Chrome user agent

Tags: macos, google-chrome

It's handy to be able to look at web server logs and tell which are my hits based on the user agent.  I can change my user agent on a per-site basis with an extension, or for a whole session by starting Chrome with a --user-agent option.

Is there a way to set the user agent permanently, short of creating a separate script that always runs Chrome with a --user-agent option?

It'd be ideal if I could just add a single string or tag to the existing user agent, something that can survive Chrome upgrades and maintain the rest of the user agent string appropriately.